# Can we have MVC 4 partial View with its own Controller & Embeded data sources

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, controller, partial-views

I have an MVC 4 partial view containing a couple of dropdown lists but when I am using this partial view in index and other pages its asking me for view bag setting for dropdown source data. My question is that can I have a partial view which will have all the dependent data loaded from its own controller and I need not to worry about the data sources population in all the ten pages where I am using it. So please advise.

Comment: You can use RenderAction instead RenderPartial.

Comment: thanks, This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ApplicationController` or `BaseController` and fill dropdown lists in it and use it in `partial`. For example see this:

**ApplicationController**

```
public class ApplicationController : Controller
    {
     public ApplicationController()
        {
            ///RoomNum list
            List<SelectListItem> RoomNumitems = new List<SelectListItem>();
            RoomNumitems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "1",
                Value = "1"
            });
            RoomNumitems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "2",
                Value = "2"
            });
            RoomNumitems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "3",
                Value = "3"
            });
            RoomNumitems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "4",
                Value = "4"
            });

            ViewData["RoomNumListItems"] = RoomNumitems;
            ///

            ///From_Price list
            List<SelectListItem> From_Price_items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            From_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "30000",
                Value = "30000"
            });
            From_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "50000",
                Value = "50000"
            });
            From_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "70000",
                Value = "70000"
            });
            From_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "100000",
                Value = "100000"
            });

            ViewData["From_PriceListItems"] = From_Price_items;
            ///

            ///To_Price list
            List<SelectListItem> To_Price_items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            To_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "100000",
                Value = "100000"
            });
            To_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "150000",
                Value = "150000"
            });
            To_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "250000",
                Value = "250000"
            });
            To_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "500000",
                Value = "500000"
            });
            To_Price_items.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = "1000000",
                Value = "1000000"
            });
            ViewData["To_PriceListItems"] = To_Price_items;
   }
}
```

**Partial view**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns admin-lbl-fildset push-8 columns">
        @Html.Label("Room number:")
    </div>
    <div class="large-8 columns admin-txt pull-4 columns">
        @Html.DropDownList("RoomNum_SelectedItem", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["RoomNumListItems"], new { @class = "admin-dropdown" })
    </div>    
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-3 columns admin-lbl-fildset push-3 columns">
        @Html.Label("To:")
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns admin-txt pull-3 columns">
        @Html.DropDownList("To_Price_SelectedItem", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["To_PriceListItems"], new { @class = "admin-dropdown" })
    </div>

    <div class="large-3 columns admin-lbl-fildset push-3 columns">
        @Html.Label("From:")
    </div>
    <div class="large-3 columns admin-txt pull-3 columns">
        @Html.DropDownList("From_Price_SelectedItem", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["From_PriceListItems"], new { @class = "admin-dropdown" })
    </div>    
</div>
```

**Cotrollers(Home for example)**

```
public class HomeController : ApplicationController
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```